# Duct hanger - place family instance Revit API

Tags: c#, api, revit-api, autodesk

i'm trying to place a family using the API (c#).

When using the NewFamiltInstace overloaded method that takes (location, symbol,host, level, structural) - i'm expecting to get the instance of the hanger family in the level i have inserted, and in the elevation of the host ( the duct).

instead - i get the duct hanger in the **ground floor** no matter what i'm doing, can any one understand why, and what sholud i do to get it in the desired level?

tried multiple overloaded methods, tried using the duct as a host, the level as a host etc.. the hangers always show up at the **floor** of ground level.

the code from my transaction:

```
using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc, "Place Family"))
{
trans.Start();


int indx = 0;
foreach (XYZ hanger_xyz in hangerCoordinates)
{

if (!hangerSymbol.IsActive)
{
hangerSymbol.Activate();
}

doc.Create.NewFamilyInstance(hanger_xyz, hangerSymbol,duct,level, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Structure.StructuralType.NonStructural);

}

trans.Commit();
}
```

'''

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

After testing all of the 11 overloaded methods for newFamilyInstance and their required arguments, and snooping around with RevitLookUp, i  managed to get the right overloded method which is:

```
FamilyInstance familyInstance = doc.Create.NewFamilyInstance(face, hanger_xyz, new XYZ(0, 1, 0), hangerSymbol);
```

face==> as a  Referemce object (extracted it from a face Face that i got from a GeoElement that i got from the desired level's floor)

hanger_xyz==>an XYZ location

new XYZ(0,1,0)==> a direction of the family as it is when it's attached to a cielling host ( got it from revitLookUp)

hangerSymbol ==> the familysymbol.